# Listview selectionchanged fires twice, How to control?

Tags: c#, listview, selectedindexchanged

after show the form, this load egain. I know This is by design. But I don't like show again.

```
    private void HandleLSVVacunacion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView SourceControl = (ListView)sender;

        if (SourceControl.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            int IdVacunacion = Convert.ToInt32(LSVVacunacion.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text.Trim());
            Formularios.FrmVacunacion f = new Formularios.FrmVacunacion();
            f.ID = IdVacunacion;
            f.HC = hc;
            f.ShowDialog();
            CargarEsquemaVacunacion(); // reload The ListView with changes; and show again the form!

        }

    }
```

Comment: call **HandleLSVVacunacion_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);**

Answer (score 0):

If your code in `CargarEsquemaVacunacion` causes a reenter in your event handler then you could remove the event handler, reload your list and reapply the event handler

```
    if (SourceControl.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        .....
        f.ShowDialog();
        try
        {
            LSVVacunacion.SelectedIndexChanged -= HandleLSVVacunacion_SelectedIndexChanged;
            CargarEsquemaVacunacion(); 
        }
        finally
        {
            LSVVacunacion.SelectedIndexChanged += HandleLSVVacunacion_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

    }
```

Notice that this code is inside a try/finally block to be sure that also in case of exceptions the event handler is reapplied to the event SelectedIndexChanged